# Get data from fetch API issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used fetch API on my front end to send a post request like this:

```
fetch('accounts/google-login', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({token : id_token})
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response:', response)
        response.json()
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log("result:", result)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The code works fine and I can return a res in my node server with this function:

```
function googleLogin(req, res) {
    accountService.googleLogin(req, res)
        .then(result => {
            console.log('result Here::', result)
            res.json(result)
        })
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
}
```

The above console log is
[image]

Here is what I get in my front-end console:

[image]

As you see I cannot get the data from the `googleLogin` function (I mean the object in the black console) and I get `undefined` instead!

How can I access to the response I send?

Comment: You can see that result: `undefined` is logged from the fetch inside that then block, I showed you the last object I pass the `res.json(result)` in the black console...

Comment: `res.json(result)` should be `res.json()`. But the actual error is the missing `return`, see my answer below. Yes it's also missing on your server but there you don't even attempt to log the body, only the response object.

Comment: using res.json() instead of res.json(result) causes an error!!

Comment: Which error? The docs say it doesn't take any argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `return` the return value of `response.json()`:

```js
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response:', response)
        return response.json()
//      ^^^^^^
    })
```

...or without the logging you could just write this:

```js
   .then(response => response.json())
```

(because one-line arrow functions implicitly return their result)

Comment: That was actually interesting